# Apostrophe and superscript in ggplot axis label r

Tags: r, ggplot2, apostrophe, superscript

reproducible example:

```
x1<-rnorm(5,5,1)
y1<-rnorm(5,5,1)
d<-data.frame(x1,y1)

ggplot(data=d,aes(x=x1,y=y1))+
  geom_point()+
  ylab(bquote('y (since year s'* ~ 1^st*' day)'))
```

I would like to add an apostrophe after "year" and I tried to add `'\\''` but it does not work.

There are already several questions asking about superscript:

[Subscripts and superscripts "-" or "+" with ggplot2 axis labels? (ionic chemical notation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34892262/subscripts-and-superscripts-or-with-ggplot2-axis-labels-ionic-chemical)

[How to write chemical formulas in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63902931/how-to-write-chemical-formulas-in-ggplot?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[ggplot labels adding superscript, how to come out of the superscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49637550/ggplot-labels-adding-superscript-how-to-come-out-of-the-superscript)

But I could not find any that combines it with an apostrophe (which is recognized by the superscript expression).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes `'` and double quotes `"` are usually interchangeable in R code.  Get the single quote you want by surrounding the string containing it with double quotes.

```r
library(ggplot2)
x1<-rnorm(5,5,1)
y1<-rnorm(5,5,1)
d<-data.frame(x1,y1)

ggplot(data=d,aes(x=x1,y=y1))+
  geom_point()+
  ylab(bquote("y (since year's"* ~ 1^st*' day)'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that was easy. I had tried but I must have messed up something else and thought it would not work.